# reducing the vector inner product to norm

Tags: inner-products

I came across these steps when I study my math lectures:

$$x_k = \operatorname*{argmin}_x \langle \nabla f(x_{k-1}),x\rangle + \frac{\eta_k} 2 \| x - x_{k-1} \|_2^2  $$
$$x_k = \operatorname*{argmin}_x \frac{\eta_k} 2 \left\|x - x_{k-1} + \frac 1 {\eta_k} \nabla f(x_{k-1})\right\|_2^2$$ 
I cannot find how the first step reduced to the second step. I tried using the relation:
$$\|x\|_2^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$$

But I still cannot find the relation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle x,x\rangle$ rather than $<x,x>.$ I change that anad did some other copy-editing.

Comment: Are you sure you meant the $\|x-x_k\|$ above? If $\eta_k$ is small, there is no solution to the first.

Comment: Also there is no way the $x_{k-1}$ can appear in the second line other than as in the $\nabla f(x_{k-1})$. If it could, it would mean that you could magically recover the argument of $\nabla f$ from the value of $\nabla f(x_{k-1})$.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm sorry I had some mistakes. Corrected them now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what point of the second formula is as you can compute
a solution to the first explicitly.

If you have $\min_x \langle g,x\rangle + {\alpha \over 2} \|x-y\|^2$ (Euclidean norm) then the solution is
$g+ \alpha(x-y)=0$ and hence $x= y- {1\over \alpha} g$.

Substituting values for the above, we see that
$x_k = x_{k-1}+{1 \over \eta_k} \nabla f(x_{k-1})$.

Hence it is true that 
$x_k = \arg\min_x \| x-x_{k-1}+{1 \over \eta_k} \nabla f(x_{k-1}) \|^2 $, but it is a strange leap, unless the author is using this
to justify some subsequent intuition or step.

Comment: The author is actually trying to show _how_ $g+ \alpha(x-y)=0$ becomes a solution to  $\min_x \langle g,x\rangle + {\alpha \over 2} \|x-y\|^2$ but with the variables that are given here because they're the relevant variables to the lecture. I'd appreciate it if you could show me how it becomes a solution. Thanks.

Comment: The function is convex in $x$ and the gradient is $g+ \alpha (x-y)$. Hence $x$ is a minimiser **iff** $x=y-{1 \over \alpha} g$.